# How do I login into Instagram with a password if I no longer own email?

Tags: security, login, instagram, account-recovery

What if you have a password to your Instagram account, but no longer have access to the email address used to register the account (nor have any sort of a Facebook accounts linked), and your account gets disabled for "suspicious activity", which resulted simply by logging into your own account with a password through a web-browser, and not following up with a prompt to provide an account photo (or something like that).

How can you henceforth login?  When trying to login through the app, a message appears about the account being disabled, and having to follow the instructions for resetting the password. However, all instructions effectively assume that the password is forgotten (not the case!), or access to the email account is available.

So, really, if I know my password, but don't have email, how am I supposed to login?

Comment: In my case, I don't even have email linked because someone else used my email id to create their account and apparently instagram didn't verify emails.

When I try to login I got suspicious activity message even though I have correct password and there is no way to send a reset link.

Answer (score 2):

If you are logged in via the app still you may be able to change the password through that. Go to Profile > Edit Profile > Change Password.

Alternatively, if your phone number is linked to your account you may be able to reset it via SMS (this may be an app only option).

Otherwise, if you no longer have access to the email registered to your Instagram account, you effectively lose access to the account. While in this case you didn't forget the password, the [relevant Instagram help page](https://help.instagram.com/358911864194456) makes it clear that they expect you to have access to the email account for your Instagram:

> If you've forgotten your password and lost access to your email account, we're unable to release the Instagram account to you. This includes accounts registered with mistyped email addresses.
>
> We understand this can be frustrating, but this policy is meant to make sure Instagram accounts don't fall into the wrong hands.

Comment: I'm not logged in via the app; I logged in via the web-interface when this happened a few days ago, and the last thing I recall was being asked to upload a profile photo, which I didn't do -- then there was no indication that I was logged in anymore, and further attempts to login all failed.

Comment: You could try the [Instagram support form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=364531043625021), but unless you can regain access to the associated email account, it is unlikely you'll ever be able to log into your Instagram.

Comment: How did you even find this form?  It's nowhere near any of the help articles linked from the failed logins.

Comment: I've sent in a request, thanks.  The whole situation is rather amusing, IMHO.

Comment: Googled it :-) Instragram, like most companies these days, eschews direct contact and doesn't make it easy to find. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but if you no longer a have access to that email account you won't be able to get you Instagram account login name unless it’s a mobile app, then you can use your phone number.

Comment: but i do know my own password!  that makes no sense!